# UITabBarController embedded in a UINavigationController

Tags: iphone, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

The main flow of my project is controlled by a UINavigationController. I need to embed a UITabBarController in one of the screens to provide 3 views. Can anyone guide me on how to do this?

Let me explain my flow a bit, so that the necessity of this becomes clear. In a typical usecase -

- The user logs in
- Picks a few filters and clicks a button
- A work queue is displayed based on these filters
- When the user picks one of the elements from this work queue, he drills down into a screen which needs to present 3 views.

  1. Most frequently used actions
  2. History of actions
  3. Manual search
- These are just used like a radio button and the user can go back and forth between these 3 views, and once he's done, he needs to return to the work queue.

The navigationcontroller is therefore at the top for me, to allow him to go back and forth between login <-> filters <-> Workqueue <-> Actions [Favorites, History, Search]

Thanks, 
Teja.

Comment: Pushing a UITabBarController doesn't work?

Comment: You know, I just realized I can do that.  Working on it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you will need to present the uitabbarcontroller modally